# MVVM LiveData slow on first time in bottomSheetFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I don't understand why my MVVM with LiveData takes a lot of time to respond within a BottomSheetFragment, but just the first time I open the fragment.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("HERE", "onViewCreated")
        abilityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[AbilityViewModel::class.java]
        setupViewModel()
        Log.d("HERE", "viewModelCreated")
        abilityViewModel.getAbilityByName(abilityName)

private fun setupViewModel() {
        abilityViewModel.abilityName.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { ability ->
            Log.d("HERE", ability.name)
            fillInfo(ability)
        })
    }
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```kotlin
class AbilityViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: AbilityRepository
    private val _abilityName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    val abilityName: LiveData<Ability>

    fun getAbilityByName(name: String) {
        _abilityName.value = name
    }

    init {
        val abilityDao: AbilityDao = MainDatabase(application, viewModelScope).abilityDao()
        repository = AbilityRepository(abilityDao)
        abilityName = Transformations.switchMap(_abilityName){abilityName ->
            repository.getAbilityByName(abilityName)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the log for the first time I open the fragment:
[image: first_time]

After the first time, both the same fragment and different fragments of the same type take zero delay in loading:
[image: second_time]

[image: third_time]

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

**EDIT**

In order to get the time in places suggested by @commonsware I did this:

```kotlin
class AbilityViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: AbilityRepository
    private val _abilityName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    val abilityName: LiveData<Ability>

    fun getAbilityByName(name: String) {
        Log.d("HERE", "getAbilityByName called")
        _abilityName.value = name
        Log.d("HERE", "getAbilityByName value assigned")
    }

    init {
        val abilityDao: AbilityDao = MainDatabase(application, viewModelScope).abilityDao()
        repository = AbilityRepository(abilityDao)
        abilityName = Transformations.switchMap(_abilityName){abilityName ->
            Log.d("HERE", "switchMap called")
            repository.getAbilityByName(abilityName)
        }
    }
}
```

However the problem does not seem to be in any of those two methods as you can see here:

[image: fourth_pic]

In addition the database is initialised when the app starts, which is before this point

**EDIT 2**

Here is the repository modified to accomodate the log:

```kotlin
class AbilityRepository(private val abilityDao: AbilityDao) {
    //fun getAbilityByName(name: String) = abilityDao.getAbilityByName(name)
    fun getAbilityByName(name: String): LiveData<Ability> {
        Log.d("HERE", "getAbilityByName called from repo")
        return abilityDao.getAbilityByName(name)
    }
}
```

However the time seems to be fine here as well
[image: fifth_pic]

Comment: Add logging to your `switchMap()` to see whether the delay is in it responding to the value or if it is in the execution of `getAbilityByName()`. If `getAbilityByName()`, is at fault, add logging there to see where the time is being taken.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I tried what you suggested but I still cannot find where the slowness might be caused. The only thing that comes to my mind is the database, however it is initialised when the app first starts which is not here.

I edited the question to show the new times

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: when I referred to `getAbilityByName()`, I was referring to the function on your repository. Your new logging suggests that the problem lies in there somewhere.

Comment: I edited the post putting the Log inside the repository function as well

Comment: That tells you at what point you *called* `getAbilityByName()`. It does not tell you how long that call took... other than an implication that it took about 14 seconds. Perhaps you could post the `AbilityRepository` implementation, or at least its `getAbilityByName()` function -- maybe something there will spark some ideas.

Comment: This is actually the whole implementation. There is nothing more than that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210070/discussion-between-fabzanna-and-commonsware).

Comment: Sorry, you caught me on a day when I'm short on sleep! :-( So, now we are down to either `abilityDao.getAbilityByName(name)` being slow, something in the `switchMap()` processing of the result being slow, or something in triggering your fragment code to run being slow. None of those are yours -- they are either from libraries or are code-generated from libraries. None should take anywhere near that long. However, I don't use `switchMap()`, and I don't have a DAO return `LiveData`, so I don't know if there are any particular issues there that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Personally, since you are using Kotlin, I would use coroutines for the DAO and have the viewmodel emit the results using the `liveData {}` builder. You're welcome to stick with what you have, but you will need to do more analysis (e.g., `return abilityDao.getAbilityByName(name).apply { Log.d("HERE", "getAbilityByName returned from repo") }`) to see which of my three scenarios is the source of the delay. You might consider joining my office hours chat, which is running right now for an hour (log in at https://wares.commonsware.com and click on the link in the banner).

Comment: The DAO extracts the data from a ROOM database. Could you please write down an example on how to implement what you described? Thank you

Comment: [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.2/FTS) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Room) demonstrates using the `liveData {}` builder to bridge between a `suspend` function in a DAO and the UI layer via a viewmodel. In my case, the sample is mostly focused on full-text search in Room.